# PHP class get 70GB memory when parse lagre XML file to array

Tags: php, xml, parsing

I use SimpleLargeXMLParser.class.php to parse huge XML file to array, but when I use memory_get_usage() to get memory used, It's output: 70284.453125 MB ~ 68GB. Can I use this class on Server have 8GB RAM?

This is class:
http://www.phpclasses.org/package/5667-PHP-Parse-XML-documents-and-return-arrays-of-elements.html

This is xml:
https://nvd.nist.gov/feeds/xml/cve/nvdcve-2.0-2015.xml.zip

```
 <?php  
    require_once('SimpleLargeXMLParser.class.php');
    $xml = "nvdcve-2.0-2015.xml";
    $parser = new SimpleLargeXMLParser();
    $parser->loadXML($xml);

    $startMemory = memory_get_usage();
    $array = $parser->parseXML(); 
    echo ((memory_get_usage() - $startMemory)/1024), ' MB';
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a streaming parser instead (like [XMLReader](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.xmlreader.php)) - this allows you to keep only the current state and the current token in memory.

Don't expect a random parser from phpclasses.org to be of a great quality.

Comment: My xml file is about 30 ~ 50MB ,  XML Reader can work well?

Comment: The file size doesn't matter. A pull parser does not parse the whole document in one go, you'll use only as much memory as is needed to parse a single token and keep the parsing state.